# Nest.js MongoDb always return results

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

So the find method always returns results even when there are no results that match the search query. What could be the reason?

Schema:

```
export const ReviewScehma = new mongoose.Schema({
    reviewId: { type: String, default: '' },
    authorName: { type: String, default: '' },
    packageIdentifier: { type: String, default: '' },
    userComment: {
        text: { type: String, default: '' },
        starRating: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});
```

Search:

```
async reviews(packageIdentifier: string) {
    const searchTerms = (packageIdentifier) ? { packageIdentifier: packageIdentifier } : {};
    const reviews = await this.reviewModel.find( searchTerms );
    if (!reviews) {
        throw new NotFoundException('There are no reviews to fetch');
    }

    return reviews;
}
```

I currently have 100 objects in my collection and only one of them is with a `packageIdentifier` and value. How can I make him return an empty array when he won't find anything? or, of course, an array of results when they do.

Currently, it always returns the whole collection.

Comment: In searchTerm you have condition like if packegeIdentifire then it will run query for matching data else it will run query for get all data via `{}`. So you need to run query if you have packegeIdentifire.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean.. If `packageIdentifier` exists I run the query with `{ packageIdentifier }` if he doesn't I run it with `{ }`.

Comment: You need to run query when you have packegeIdentifire data right?

Comment: Yes, of course, I run a query on which `packageIdentifier` exists or empty `{ }`

Answer (score 1):

Empty query filters cause Mongoose/MongoDB to return all documents in the model, which causes this issue.
In order to achieve the desired functionality, you should pass `strict` and `strictQuery` options to your schema.

```js
export const ReviewScehma = new mongoose.Schema({
    reviewId: { type: String, default: '' },
    authorName: { type: String, default: '' },
    packageIdentifier: { type: String, default: '' },
    userComment: {
        text: { type: String, default: '' },
        starRating: { type: Number, default: 0 }
}, { strict: true, strictQuery: false });
```

For reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strictQuery

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find data based on matching value then you need to change find query with condition if you are passing `{}` it will return all documents.

```
async reviews(packageIdentifier: string) {
  const reviews = await this.reviewModel.find({$and: [{ packageIdentifier: {$exists: true}}, { packageIdentifier  }]});
 if (!reviews) {
    throw new NotFoundException('There are no reviews to fetch');
  }

    return reviews;
}
```

It will return data if there are matching documents else it will return `[]`.

Comment: This is not what I asked for.. I want to get a specific object with `packageIdentifier` of XXX, if there are no objects with this `packageIdentifier` nor with this key, don't return them or return empty array.

Comment: i have update code please check it should work for you.

Comment: I am getting an error: `Cannot find name '$and'.`

Comment: Oh I have missed {} try now it should work.

Comment: No, still return all results..